# Hiding the field label when creating a content type

Tags: entities, nodes

I have created a content type called "Design" in which there are 3 fields. When creating this content type I want to hide the label of fields. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Please go to admin/structure/types/manage/[your-content-type]/display

[image]
And you can hide labels accordingly.